# AVaudioPlayer not working and mp3 located in Compile Bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, mp3, avfoundation

I have mp3 file in Copy Bundle Resources and this my code

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"mymp3" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fileData error:&error];
[player prepareToPlay];
```

but it doesn't play what is the problem ?

FYI: AVFoundation.framework is included.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play]; //missing play action
```

If that doesn't help try this

```
@interface AudioPlayerViewController : UIViewController {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}
```

//in your *.m file

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mymp3.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0; // 0.0 - no volume; 1.0 full volume

        if (audioPlayer == nil)
            NSLog([error description]);             
        else 
            [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: are you testing this in simulator or actual device? Try a different mp3 and make sure your device is not in mute/vibrate

Comment: I tried in both simulator and actual device, I'm really confused with this I did this before and it works !

Comment: dont' define the AVAudioPlayer locally. Put it in your *.h file. See updated code above

Comment: Yes, sure I made like this

Comment: so did it work? did you remove "AVAudioPlayer *player"

Comment: GOT IT!! Yes it works after remove AVAudioPlayer *player Thanks alot Mr, Sam but what is the problem was to understand coding :) just for information ..